# Squeeze/Lenny compilation : Library Link error

Tags: debian, compiling, gcc, c++, glibc

I've got a problem here : I have a C++ Library ("DataTsBroad") and a C++ Test app ("DataTsBroadTest"), to test it.
Actually, the Lib and the Test app are both compiled an a Debian Lenny.

Now, i want to continue to compile my Test app on a Debian Lenny (customer constraint), but I would compile my lib on a Squeeze or a Wheezy to work on the last Debian releases.

So, I successfully compiled my Lib on a Squeeze, But, after, when I try to compile my Test app with this Lib on the Lenny, it fails!
There is a Link Error:

> > Linking CXX executable DataTsBroadTest
> >     /home/nis/pezierg/test/ProductMak/Export/DataTsBroad/L64/Release/libDataTsBroad64.so:
> >     **undefined reference to `std::ctype::_M_widen_init() const@GLIBCXX_3.4.11'**
> >     collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
> >     make[2]: *** [DataTsBroadTest] Error 1
> >     make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/DataTsBroadTest.dir/all] Error 2
> >     make: *** [all] Error 2

The problem is certainly due to **ostream** C++ Lib, I tried to comment all it's uses in my Lib and it works.

But how can I really fix the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to come from use a different version of Glibc: you compiled the library on Squeeze and the application on Lenny (with the lib from Squeeze).

Take a look to the output of:

`ldd /home/nis/pezierg/test/ProductMak/Export/DataTsBroad/L64/Release/libDataTsBroad64.so`